# Overlapping Roads And Better Intersections in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, sld, road

I've been using geoserver for a month now. Obviously, I'm a beginner. I have a problem that I can't find a solution. There are many overlapping roads and intersections here.

Is that possible to print first the smaller width so it will be placed under the larger road?

How can I make a better intersections here?

[image: Roundabout]

[image: Overlapping]

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`

  `<NamedLayer>
    <Name>road_benim</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>A orange line style</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>`


`<!--Width >16-->`

 `<Rule>
  <Name>18</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>          
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>18</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>25000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>2000000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">.1</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
     </Rule>`

 `<Rule>
  <Name>18</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>18</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>10000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>25000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">10</CssParameter>          
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`

 `<Rule>
  <Name>18</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>18</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>5000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>10000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">15</CssParameter>         
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">10</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`         

 `<Rule>
  <Name>18</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>18</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>2500</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>5000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">28</CssParameter>          
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">23</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`   

 `<Rule>
  <Name>18</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>18</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>0</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>2500</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">40</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">35</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`                                                                     


        `<!--Width >8-->`

 `<Rule>
  <Name>16</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>16</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>25000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>2000000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">.1</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
     </Rule>`

 `<Rule>
  <Name>16</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>16</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>10000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>25000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">10</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`         

 `<Rule>
  <Name>16</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>16</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>5000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>10000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">15</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">10</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`

 `<Rule>
  <Name>16</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>16</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>2500</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>5000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">28</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">23</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`  

 `<Rule>
  <Name>16</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>16</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>0</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>2500</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">40</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">35</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>` 

`<!--Width 8-->`

 `<Rule>
  <Name>12</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>12</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>25000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>2000000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">.1</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
     </Rule>`      

 `<Rule>
  <Name>12</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>12</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>10000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>25000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">10</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`   

 `<Rule>
  <Name>12</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>12</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>5000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>10000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">15</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">10</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`

 `<Rule>
  <Name>12</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>12</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>2500</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>5000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">28</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">23</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`  

 `<Rule>
  <Name>12</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>12</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>0</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>2500</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">40</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">35</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`      

`<!--Width >8-->`

 `<Rule>
  <Name>10</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>25000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>2000000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">.1</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
     </Rule>`      

 `<Rule>
  <Name>10</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>10000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>25000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">10</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>   
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`   

 `<Rule>
  <Name>10</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>5000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>10000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">15</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">10</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`

 `<Rule>
  <Name>10</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>2500</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>5000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">28</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter> 
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">23</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`  

 `<Rule>
  <Name>10</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>0</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>2500</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">40</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>            
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">35</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`        

`<!--Width >4-->`

 `<Rule>
  <Name>8</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>10000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>2000000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">.1</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
     </Rule>`      

 `<Rule>
  <Name>8</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>5000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>10000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">10</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`   

 `<Rule>
  <Name>8</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>2500</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>5000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">15</CssParameter>       
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">10</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`  

 `<Rule>
  <Name>8</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>0</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>2500</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">28</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">23</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`

`<!--width >4-->`

 `<Rule>
  <Name>6</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>10000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>2000000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">.1</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
     </Rule>`      

 `<Rule>
  <Name>6</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>5000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>10000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`   

 `<Rule>
  <Name>6</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>2500</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>5000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">6</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`  

 `<Rule>
  <Name>6</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>0</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>2500</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">12</CssParameter> 
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">7</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`      

`<!--width 2-->`

 `<Rule>
  <Name>4</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>10000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>2000000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">.1</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
     </Rule>`      

 `<Rule>
  <Name>4</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>5000</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>10000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>  
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`

 `<Rule>
  <Name>4</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>2500</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>5000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">4</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`  

 `<Rule>
  <Name>4</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>width</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <MinScaleDenominator>0</MinScaleDenominator>
       <MaxScaleDenominator>2500</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">8</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>  
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
           <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer> 
     </Rule>`    

      `</FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's done! I just added this at the most bottom part of my `<Rule>`:

`<VendorOption name="sortBy">width</VendorOption>`

using `name="sortBy"` will order features based on a  “width” attribute.